# Can we see which moderator has dealt with a flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

My question is rather simple:

Is there a way to see which moderator has dealt with a flag we raised?

On Stack Overflow it is possible to see who edited, reviewed and so on a post. However, i recently noticed that one cannot see who handles the raised flags and that got me curious.

I thought there must be a good reason for this and I searched for an answer on Stack Overflow `META`, but I have not been able to find one.

Comment: There's not. No.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I am not sure why people downvote my question. It is a perfectly legit question and i suspect of interest to other users too.

Comment: if you believe there was an issue while handling your flag or if you think it was marked incorrectly, you can raise _that_ issue here in meta. Either the community or any of the moderators will respond

Comment: and why you want this ? when he will decline you will catch him! ...all the moderator should be the same and doing the same job, so a moderator is a moderator no need to know the account behind

Comment: `I am not sure why people downvote my question` --> again a frustration about downvotes :) .. downvotes here aren't the same as the main site, you can get -20 for a legit and well structured question.

Comment: Downvotes are dished out much more liberally on Meta which is also why they don't actually influence your score. No worries. The thought process behind the votes on this question is probably that moderator anonymity is a very important part of protecting them from harassment, this protection should never be weakened, and there no good reason to even think about doing that

Comment: ... which doesn't mean you shouldn't have asked the question. It's perfectly fine. Sometimes valid answers and questions end up with negative votes here. It's happened to all of us, [even our Founding Fathers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=144)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for this, i was just curious why this is the case considering that SO is a very open site. I think an answer or comment is always better expressing one's thoughts than a mysterious meta downvote!

Comment: Take the easy way out: whatever has gone wrong, blame them all :)

Comment: @PearlySpencer I'm also somewhat curious as to why you'd like to know which moderator handled your flag. If you'd like to edit that into the question, I think it would help some people better understand where you're coming from, but if you don't want to, that's fine too; it's a perfectly reasonable question as-is.

Comment: Users who hang out on Meta are very protective of StackOverflow tradition and culture and (in my experience) are very ready to downvote questions that challenge that tradition and culture.

Comment: I find this a good question, it is certainly valid and it is good that the answer is clearly given in case others want to know it. If it were tagged "feature request" however, I would have downvoted it immediately. As Pekka has already commented, don't worry too much about downvotes on meta, they are pretty harmless (for your reputation), and often express some disagreement on whatever is implied, not necessarily that the question/discussion deserves to be deleted or not to be asked.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As Jon already confirmed, you cannot see or know easily which moderator handled your flag, at least not from your flag history. [And moderators won't always know easily who flagged either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226146/158100) (when handling the mod queue that is)

With 10K privilege you can see deleted posts which makes it possible to have a good guess who handled a flag, if that involved deleting the post.

Sometimes moderators mention in chat that they handled flags you raised, basically to help fine-tune the process between flaggers and moderators. In rare cases I ping a moderator in chat to have a look at my pending flags, in which case I know for sure who handled them.

When a flag is handled in a way that surprises you, you can raise a meta post. When the moderator sees fit they might explain their reasoning for (not) taking a certain action.

It is worth mentioning that until last year moderators signed mod-messages with their own name. As that caused backlash the template has been adjusted to only sign-off with *SO moderator team*.
The trend is to protect moderators identity so they can focus on their job at hand and not run the risk of being called out for every flag they mis-judged. So don't expect a change in policy to include which moderator handled your flag.

Comment: I think protecting mods from off-site and (IIRC in one case?) real-world harassment by crazy individuals also played a role in last year's decision

Comment: @Pekka웃 yeah Brad can tell you all about that .... sad but true.

Comment: Just to note while comment flags in the queue aren't shown with the flagger like post flags it's possible (albeit it with some clicking through stuff) to get that info. For most comment flags it's not really massively important who flagged them as a lot of them are quick glance "yup... doesn't need to stay - delete". Sometimes though you look at some of them and you think "ummm... something is going on here" and find a deleted spat in comments and it turns out two users are going around flagging the other's comments etc... tldr: possible to get but rarely of any use.

Comment: @rene what happened? any related posts?

Comment: @ljedrz IIRC their employer was called and that wasn't to give a positive testimonial ...

Answer (score 0):

I agree in theory that it would be nice to see how problematic users are dealt with. However, in practice, that information could be misused.

For example, let's say user X received a warning by private modmail for persistent abusive language. The exact wording of that warning would still be private, but anyone in possession of the knowledge that X has received a warning could misuse that when talking to X. For example, comments could take on a tone that taunted user X for the admonishments they'd received, which in turn might exacerbate their poor behaviour.

Part of the moderation code here is that users should be allowed to redeem themselves, and a negative part of their history does not follow them around unduly. Moreover, mods won't comment publicly on an issue unless they have express permission to do so. This helps keep the peace a great deal.

I appreciate that there is a difficult balance to be struck: moderation should be as open as possible, so that there is no possibility of abuse of power (see the complete lack of oversight in Reddit subs for what can happen in those circumstances). However, an aggrieved party can come to Meta and air their complaint about moderation quite freely, so I'd be easily persuaded that things are correct as they are.